# Can you develop an internal business application for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone app without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore)

My boss had an idea to develop an application that would be used for a few hundred contractors/employees and deploy it on an iPhone. So basically an internal business application that is an extension of the home-office application for mobile workers.

I was under the impression that it is only possible to distribute applications (except in a testing mode that expires frequently) to an iPhone via the Apple Store, and that Apple will only accept applications that are for general use. Not something that only a few hundred people world wide could use (say the data would be restricted to credentials that would only be given to such people).

Is my impression correct, or does Apple allow that kind of development?

EDIT: OK, my impression is wrong, at least partially. But here the company does not have 500 employees. Is it then not possible?

Comment: Asked several times already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072664/private-iphone-apps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144946/b2b-programming-on-ipad-and-iphone

Comment: @indiv, thanks, StackOverflow's search is inadequate at time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have developed an app for a client's internal use and have had it distributed it on the App Store, using a standard developer account (the $99 one).  You can find it here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evolve-2010/id348772647?mt=8

I was pretty surprised it was approved (I had the client prepping for a massive ad-hoc distribution). If you're developing something requiring credentials, I'd provide a test user/pass to Apple when you submit.

So, good luck, and have a back up plan.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can purchase an Enterprise Development License for $299 USD.

This allows company distribution for organizations large than a certain size. I believe 500 employees, but [check the site](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/).

Answer (score 1):

I've heard rumors and anecdotes about companies with less than 500 employees being able to negotiate plans with Apple. Apple does have reps that work behind the scenes with enterprise users. Probably takes longer to get it running. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

If your company has greater than 500 employees and a Dun & Bradstreet number, you can register for the Enterprise Developer Program @ developer.apple.com/iphone - this will permit you to do what you desire.

Comment: But what about companies with less than 500 employees?

Comment: You cannot register for the Enterprise Developer Program if you do not meet the requirements they specify.